# Understanding Complex Differentiation

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm trying to understand complex differentiation, and I am confused about how the partial derivatives relate. First, a function $f:V\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ on a open set $V$ of the complex plan is complex differentiable if the limit

$$\underset{h\rightarrow 0}{\lim}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$$
is exists for every point in $V$. $f$ can be written in the form $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ where $u$ and $v$ are the real and imaginary parts of $f$ respectively. If a function is complex differentiable, then it must satisfy the famous Cauchy-Riemann equations: $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$ where 
$$ u_x(x,y)=\underset{h\rightarrow 0}{\lim}\frac{u(x+h,y)-u(x,y)}{h}$$
My textbook (in the appendix) goes on to say that using the CR equtions, we see that
$$f'=u_x+iv_x$$
I do not understand how to justify the equation above. $f'$ is the derivative of $f$ in terms of $z$, but the right side of the equation is in terms of the partial derivatives. How does one derive this formula? I know that a complex function is complex differentiable if and only if it is real differentiable and satisfies the CR equations and that if a complex function has continuous partial derivatives and satisfies the CR equations at a point is complex differentiable at that point.

Comment: Which textbook do you use?

Comment: Complex Made Simple by Ullrich.

Answer (score 5):

Writing your limits with an $h$ makes both equations look like the same limiting procedure. But there is a subtle difference: in your first equation we have $h \in \mathbb{C}$, whereas the second equation is real and hence $h \in \mathbb{R}$.

Consequently the first equation is a lot *stronger* than the second. Instead of approaching $0$ only from the left or right, $h$ can do all kinds of things in the complex plane. The existence of the limit in your first equation then means that it does **not** matter, which approach to zero we choose.

In particular we can be boring and go to zero along the real (or complex) axis. This boils down to restricting $h$ to be real in the first equation. In formulas, we obtain for a complex differentiable function 
\begin{align}
f'(z) &= 
\lim_{\mathbb{C} \ni h \to 0} \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{\mathbb{R} \ni h \to 0} \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{\mathbb{R} \ni h \to 0} \frac{\big(u(z+h)+iv(z+h)\big)-\big(u(z)+iv(z)\big)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{\mathbb{R} \ni h \to 0} \frac{u(z+h)-u(z)}{h} 
+ i\lim_{\mathbb{R} \ni h \to 0} \frac{v(z+h)-v(z)}{h} \\
&= u_x(z) + iv_x(z). 
\end{align}

Here we have used that taking limits is linear, the complex numbers directly decompose into real and imaginary part and that $f$ is continuously differentiable, i. e. the limits we took all exist.

Comment: By following a similar logic, one can derive the Cauchy-Riemann equations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations

Answer (score 2):

I think you can find all ingredients in Ullrich's book on pages 4-6.

Ullrich explains that $f$ is complex differentiable at $z$ iff there exists $a \in  \mathbb C$ such that $f(z+h) = f(z) +a \cdot h + o(h)$. Then $f'(z) = a$.

The map $L : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C, L(h) = a \cdot h = f'(z)\cdot h,$ is $\mathbb C$-linear and thus trivially also $\mathbb R$-linear.

Regarding $L$ as an $\mathbb R$-linear map, we can express it as a real matrix with respect to the basis $\{1, i\}$ of $\mathbb C$. If $a = \alpha + i\beta$, then this matrix is
$$M(L) = \left( \begin{array}{rrr}
\alpha  & -\beta  \\                                              
\beta & \alpha   \\                                              
\end{array}\right) .  $$
This is a well-known fact from linear algebra and can easily verified by writing $h = \mu + i\nu$ and comparing $M(L) \cdot \left( \begin{array}{rrr}
\mu\\                                              
\nu \end{array}\right)$ and $a \cdot h = (\alpha + i\beta)\cdot (\mu + i\nu)$.

Ullrich also shows that $f = u + iv$ is real differentiable which means that there exists an $\mathbb R$-linear map $L'$ such that $f(z+h) = f(z) + L'(h) + o(h)$. Expressing $L'$ as a real matrix yields
$$M(L') = \left( \begin{array}{rrr}
u_x(z) & u_y(z)  \\                                              
v_x(z) & v_y(z)  \\                                              
\end{array}\right) = \left( \begin{array}{rrr}
u_x(z) & -v_x(z)  \\                                              
v_x(z) & u_x(z)  \\                                              
\end{array}\right)$$
due to the CR equations.

We clearly have $L' = L$. Comparing the matrices we see that $\alpha = u_x(z), \beta = v_x(z)$ which implies 
$$f'(z) = a = \alpha + i\beta = u_x(z) + iv_x(z).$$

PS. I think the direct proof given by Michael Heins is easier. Ullrich seems to focus on the relationship between complex and real differentiability.

Answer (score 0):

You know that $f'(z)=$
$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
 u_x & -v_x \\ v_x & u_x
\end{array}\right]
$ then $f'(a,b)$ equal

$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
 u_x & -v_x \\ v_x & u_x
\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{c} a\\ b \end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c} au_x -bv_x\\ av_x+bu_x \end{array}\right]$
 The book consider $a+ib = \left[\begin{array}{c} a\\ b \end{array}\right]$
And $f'(a,b)$ is going to be as I write earlier the matrix multiplication where the top entry is the real part and the bottom is the imaginary part and if you evaluate $(a+ib)(u_x+iv_x)$ and write that as a 2x1 matrix you will see it is the same